# rayon::str::Lines<'_'> is not an iterator

Tags: file-io, rust, rayon

I'm trying process a file line by line in Rust and parallelise this using Rayon. It complains of the following

```
rayon::str::Lines<'_>` is not an iterator
   = help: the trait `std::iter::Iterator` is not implemented for 
   = note: required by `std::iter::IntoIterator::into_iter`
```

This is what the code looks like so far

```rust
use rayon::prelude::*;
use std::fs;

fn main() {
    let file_content = match fs::read_to_string("input.txt") {
        Ok(s) => s,
        Err(e) => {
            eprintln!("Error: {}", e);
            std::process::exit(1);
        }
    };

    file_content = 5;

    for line in file_content.par_lines() {
        println!("{}", line);
    }

    std::process::exit(0);
}
```

Am I missing a trait definition? How could I fix this error?

Comment: `std::process::exit(0)` is redundant; exiting main normally does that. You also *probably* want to use `panic!` instead of the other call to `exit`.

Comment: What exactly is your **question**? You've provided code and an error message; what do you want from us?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use parallel iterators with the (non-parallel) `for` loop.

Instead, use `.for_each(|| …)` callback on the parallel iterator.

Alternatively, first call `.collect::<Vec<_>>()`, and then non-parallel `for`.

For more advanced cases you can also send results to a [channel](https://lib.rs/crossbeam-channel) in parallel, and then use non-parallel `for` to read from the channel.